# Criar uma barra inferior com Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Existe algum plugin jQuery que crie uma barra de opções como a do projeto [PHP Debug Bar](http://phpdebugbar.com/)? Alguém tem alguma sugestão de implementação?

O "Messages | Request | Timeline" é uma barra fina e fixa no rodapé do site e ao clicar "Messages" mostra o conteúdo "hello world" etc.

[image: menu]

Comment: *Muito* interessante essa Debug Bar! . . .  Mas porque você quer em jQuery?

Comment: Vi este Debug Bar no Zend Framework 2 e gostaria de implementar um menu neste estilo para um projeto. Não queria recriar esse app apenas utilizar a ideia deste menu, entendeu? Tenho um pouco de dificuldade em Jquery e queria de sugestões de como criar algo semelhante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conferindo o código fonte](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/) é possível ver como alguma página implementa o desenho e a funcionalidade.

No caso do site do PHP Debug Bar, é uma questão de fixar um menu no rodapé e mostrar elementos abaixo do menu quando algum item é selecionado. Não achei os scripts no site, mas um jQuery básico vai cuidar de mostrar/esconder os elementos.

A estrutura do HTML é:

```html
<div class="phpdebugbar">
    <div class="phpdebugbar-header">        
        <a href="javascript:" class="phpdebugbar-tab" data-tab="messages">Messages</a>
        <!-- OUTROS MENUS -->
    </div>

    <div class="phpdebugbar-body">
        <div class="phpdebugbar-panel active" id="tab-messages">
            <!-- CONTEÚDO A SER MOSTRADO -->
            <button class="phpdebugbar-close-btn">fechar</button>
        </div>
        <!-- OUTRAS TABS -->
    </div>
</div>
```

O CSS:

```css
.phpdebugbar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.phpdebugbar-header {
  min-height: 26px;
}

.phpdebugbar-header:after {
  clear: both;
}

.phpdebugbar-body {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.phpdebugbar-panel {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.phpdebugbar-panel.active {
  display: block;
}
```

E o jQuery:

```js
$('.phpdebugbar-tab').click( function() {
    // Esconder painel ativo
    $('.phpdebugbar-panel.active').removeClass('active');
    // Marcar novo painel como ativo
    var tab = $(this).data('tab');
    $('#tab-'+tab).addClass('active');
    // Mostra o body se não estiver visivel
    if( $('.phpdebugbar-body').is(":hidden") ) {
        $('.phpdebugbar-body').toggle();
    }
});

$('.phpdebugbar-close-btn').click( function() {
    $('.phpdebugbar-body').toggle();
});
```

[**Este**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/ruo8yhgn/3/) é o fiddle do código acima. E [**este**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/p2ewr7c1/2/) é usando o HTML e o CSS do site (carregando o Font Awesome via CDN), fiz só umas poucas modificações no código original e ainda precisa de uma boa limpeza.

Comment: Cara, muito bom. Era exatamente o que eu estava querendo.

Answer (score 2):

cara se o proprio console do navegador ....

aperta F12 no chrome tem varias opções você vai em console ...

para ser mais top usa o FireBug
https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/firebug/